# How to display the result of a query if records exist else show no records exist in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select (case when exists(select client_id, source_type, date(created_at) as dt, count(id)  
from integration_customers ic
where client_id = '101' and date(created_at )= current_date-20 
group by client_id, source_type , dt order by dt desc) 
then  'record exists'
else 'record doesnt exist' end) as Recordavailability
```

I used this code but it only shows record exists, what if i want to see the records if they exist else display records don't exist?

I am new to postgresql to so any help is welcome.

Comment: In SQL, a result set has to have fixed columns, or, at the very least, the _types_ and number of columns of the result set must be fixed.  Maybe show us exactly what you want to see here.

Comment: I want to run this query and return those 4 columns if records exist otherwise i just want to display records don't exist

Answer (score 0):

the following code can help you with that .

```
SELECT * INTO "NameOfTable" FROM "TableName" WHERE "ColumnName" = "TheValueYouWant";
IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not Found', "TheValueYouWant";
```

Comment: actually i am returning multiple columns here. the select query in the question returns 4 columns. I want to return those four columns if records are found otherwise i want to return records don't exist.

Comment: Select column1,column2,column3,column4 from table where condition ;IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not Found', "TheValueYouWant";

Comment: The value you want in a specific column in your condition

Comment: What is meant here by "TheValueYouWant"
Example:
select count(id) as Numberofrecords, source_type, Date(created_at) as dt,client_id 
from integration_customers ic
where client_id='101'
group by source_type ,dt,client_id 
order by dt desc;
IF NOT FOUND THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not Found',???  ;
what should i enter here?

Comment: Client id"101" is the vaue

Comment: select count(id) as Numberofrecords, source_type, Date(created_at) as dt,client_id 
from integration_customers ic
where client_id='101'
group by source_type ,dt,client_id 
order by dt desc
IF NOT FOUND THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not Found','101';
on using this query syntax error throws near if

Comment: Add a semicolon before if

Comment: on adding a semicolon these two statements are considered different and if statement throws error